# Sprite Image reference using TTML

Tags: sprite, ttml

Can I use TTML to create cue that link thumbnail image file coordinates to a range of time the thumbnail represent.

I would like to use TTML to create the cue reference of the thumbnail sprite image created for a duration of the video.

I am aware that this can be done using webvvt, but wanted to check whether this can be done for TTML.

Regards